# Eclipse not allowing svn compare and giving resource not existing in repo error

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am using team svn plugin in my eclipse helios pydev project.I deleted a repository file in eclipse and then committed the changes and all went well. The file got removed from repository fine.

Lets say package structure is like this in repo
dev/
   folderA/
       folderB/
       C.py

In eclipse dev is the project name.

I deleted C.py from eclipse and commited using svn team commit option.
It worked fine.

Now when I try to compare folderA with repo folderA, Eclipse try to compare C.py from the revision which obviously is not there and does not allow compare to work.
Somehow eclipse has that file in its memory.
How can I make eclipse know that file is deleted and is not supposed to be there in first place?

Comment: May be do update from repo before comparing?

Comment: actually I have uncommited code in my working copy, so cant update. Was comparing just to see how much my code has changed and hence the problem.

Comment: Update shouldnt remove your uncommited code, safe hand you may take backup of uncommited code and try update.

Comment: ok so updating actually brings changes done by others and does not interfere with code changes done by ourselves. After update error got removed. Thanx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that was just a synchronisation problem as after updating from the repo the problem was solved.